# MS-Word Edit Bold Resume Template

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to edit the color of highlighted section in MS Word for MAC. How can I achieve that?

[image: Bold Resume Template]

[Here is the sample file.](https://ufile.io/ogvto4ed)

Comment: Have you tried to double-click on it? What is the template's name?

Comment: Which version of Office for Mac are you using now? Could you please provide the templaet name or the shared link for us? Then we have a chance to test.

Comment: Highlighted section? The grey arrow? Select it and look for a shape context tab. That should give you the editing tools you'll need. Again, version of Office is important.

Comment: @Emily I am using Microsoft Word For Mac version 16.49 and the template name is Bold Resume. I was unable to find that template online. Looks like It comes bundled in the application.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I have tried clicking and double clicking but nothing gets selected. I can select the content but neither the border nor the annotated area.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Somehow I am unable to select that area. I might be missing something. I don't have much experience with Office suite.

Comment: You could link a sample document with this here. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Thank You for the suggestion. I have added the sample file.

Comment: Have you read my Answer and tried it? The key is that the shape is in the first-page header. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

The shape is in your header.

[image: screenshot]

Edit the header and select it.

Headers and footers can have content that is outside the header or footer area. This is how Watermarks are created.

Comment: @Rahul K Jha   Charles Kenyon is right. After select this shape, you may change color via "Shape Fill" feature.